# Cannot update an MS SQL datetime field with PHP

Tags: php, sql-server, datetime

I am trying to update a DATETIME field in my MSSQL Server (2012) with the following PHP code:

```
$currentDate = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
            $query = "  UPDATE Members
                        SET lastNotificationCheck = '?'
                        WHERE memberID=?;";
            $stmt = sqlsrv_prepare($this->con, $query, array(&$currentDate, &$_SESSION['member_id']));
            $execute = sqlsrv_execute($stmt);

            if ($execute === false) {
                die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));

                return false;
            } else {
                return true;
            }
```

The above is returning the following error:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => 22018 [SQLSTATE] => 22018 [1] => 245 [code] => 245 [2] => [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0][SQL Server]Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '2014-11-10 11:30:35' to data type int. [message] => [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0][SQL Server]Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '2014-11-10 11:30:35' to data type int. ) )
```

The weird thing is (I think) is that the following query is working perfectly in SQL Server Management Studio:

```
UPDATE Members
SET lastNotificationCheck = '2014-11-10 11:18:00'
WHERE memberID=1000004;
    enter code here
```

I have tried to generate the date in some different ways (date() and new DateTime()), but the query always fail when executed through PHP.

The Members table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Members](
[memberID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[membername] [varchar](20) NOT NULL,
[email] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
[password] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
[joindate] [datetime] NOT NULL,
[lastlogin] [datetime] NULL,
[lastNotificationCheck] [datetime] NULL
```

I hope someone can see what could be wrong.

Comment: Try removing the quotes in `'?'`, they will be added automatically if the value is a string.

Comment: Yes that was it.. I didn't know that :) Thank you! If you create an answer, i'll accept it. otherwise, can I close the question ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the quotes in '?', they will be added automatically if the value is a string. If you add them as well the result will be `''value''`.

```
$query = "  UPDATE Members
  SET lastNotificationCheck = ?
  WHERE memberID=?;";
$stmt = sqlsrv_prepare($this->con, $query, array(&$currentDate, &$_SESSION['member_id']));
```

Comment: Alternatively you could just use `SET lastNotificationCheck=NOW()`.